# How to use c# variable within Google embedded map

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, iframe, razor

I have integrated Google embedded maps on my ASP.Net Web Application. My issue is that I would like to set the parameter to  the variable Rest. Is it possible to populate an iframe source with a c# variable?

**Current Code**

```
foreach (var Rest in Model.Restaurantview)
{
     int Id = Rest.id;
     <div class="col-md-6">
         <iframe width="600"
                 height="450"
                 frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                 src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAYfNN-pP_oidwvDTANO02CYvV6WwoTMP4
        &q=LeKesh,Oxford">
         </iframe>
     </div>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 @{
     var variabletobeused = "LeKesh,Oxford";
 }
 <div class="col-md-6">
                            <iframe width="600"
                                    height="450"
                                    frameborder="0" style="border:0"
                                    src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=AIzaSyAYfNN-pP_oidwvDTANO02CYvV6WwoTMP4&q=@variabletobeused"></iframe>

                        </div>
```

Yup just use @, see above example